# how to create 3 dynamic dependent select box in jsp with struts2

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, struts2

```
function myfunction(var1) {
    var params =var1; //values for passing to struts if any
    var resultStringX = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"loadImportAasthiPage1.action", // struts2 action call
        data: params,
        async: false
        }).responseText;
    // the returning result will be stored in resultStringX variable        
    resultStringX=$.trim(regn);         
}
```

```xml
<s:form action="loadImportAasthiPage1">
    <s:select label="What's your favor search engine" id="ward"
            headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Search Engines"
            list="wardList" 
            name="wardNum" 
            value="wardNumber" onchange="myfunction(10)" />

    Regn List 
    <s:select name="propertyId"  
        list="propertyList" listKey="propertyId" 
        id="regn" listValue="regnName" 
        headerKey="0" headerValue="--select--" />

</s:form>
```

```java
String wardNum;
```

I am getting null value of wardNum.

Please tell how to pass values from JavaScript to action class

Comment: You need to create a Setter on your action, as a start...

Comment: What errors do you have in the console?